# Importing module from virtual environment

Tags: python

I am completely new to python.I was able to install python in my macos and able to print hello world.I want to test out one 3rd party library and followed instructions from their documentation like below.

```
pip install virtualenv

virtualenv -p python3 breeze_venv

source breeze_venv/bin/activate

pip install --upgrade breeze-connect
```

I installed above things and my folder structure looks like below

[image]

Now in index.py  , when i try to import the module like below

```
from breeze_connect import BreezeConnect
breeze = BreezeConnect(api_key="123")
```

I get following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'breeze_connect'
```

sorry if my question is newbie , today is my first day of python.

Answer (score 1):

Your `index.py` file (and all your other source code for that matter) is supposed to be next to the `venv` folder.

```
breeze
|- breeze_venv/
    |- bin/
    |- lib/
|- index.py
```

You can also check if PyCharm / VSCode / ... picked up on the `venv` you created earlier.

Answer (score 0):

i try to explain the how the thing go then we can resolve the issue here
when you install python on your system you have local python installed some where in your system that work with this command on your terminal

`python the_path_to_file_to_run.py`

when you install virtual environment as you do you install python on the folder you specified with this command
`virtualenv -p python3 breeze_venv`
in your case **breeze_venv** folder
the you activate the virtual env with `source breeze_venv/bin/activate`
when virtual env is activated as long as you are in there you don't work with you local version of python you work with your venv version
you can see if your virtual env is activated by this

`(name_of_you_virtual_env) mac-username`

if it is not activated you terminal command prompt is like normal

`mac-usrename`

if you can verify that your are in virtual environment then you can run application with
`python path_to_your_script.py`

if you want to use vs code to run you python make sure in bottom right of the vs code change the python interpreter to use your virtual environment

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments